# Xamarin Entry Custom Renderer FAILS to change Text Color! Why?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

This test case FAILS to change the text color of a Xamarin Entry. I can change the backcolor to few specific colors??!!! Actually, no matter what I do, I can change the text color of an Entry.

**How to reproduce**

1. Visual Studio 2017 - Open new cross plateform project/Net Standard Master-Detail / Android only for the purpose.
2. Add entry custom renderer to your android. Code sample here:

   ```
   using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
   using Xamarin.Forms;
   using Android.Content;

   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(MyCondoCPML.Droid.MyEntryRenderer))]
   namespace MyCondoCPML.Droid
   {
       class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
       {
           public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
           {
           }

           protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
           {
               base.OnElementChanged(e);
               if (Control != null) {
                   Control.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Red);                    
                   Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.LightGreen);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. RUN by USB on api 24 - android version 7 (Samsung S5 NEO)

**Result**

Background is lightgreen BUT the text color STAYS BLACK! WHY?! I tried everything. Lol. Until you guys tell me what of course...

Regards,

P.S. Yes, i tried the Xamarin tutorial/doc/samples/etc. Yes, I read anything i could on stack, google, c# corner, etc... 
P.P.S My behaviors fail to change the text color (red) as well :(

Martin

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the colors you should use:

```
//Text Color - When typing
 Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.SteelBlue);
//Placeholder text color
Control.SetHintTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
```

Perhaps you are missing the Hint Text Color. The rest is just fine, if you don't have any exception and if the method is called, there is no other way to achieve this. Also, in your xaml, check if are you setting any different color.

Comment: Hi, let's say I ONLY want to change the text color and not the placeholder color. Why this line doesnt change the textcolor to red? Control.SetTextColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Red); the text of the entry stays black...

Comment: It should work only with that, are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: No exceptions. The entry stays background white and text color black. Which is probably the default. i develop android with usb cable.. android 7, api 24...

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint, to see if the methods are being called?

Comment: Yes. The code is executed. No errors/exceptions whatsoever... I can type in the entry on my phone but the text is black. Strangely, I can change the background color or text properties but not the textcolor or hinttextcolor...

Comment: it WORKS in emulator api 25, nougat but doesnt work usb cable to my android 7, api 24?! why? food for thought, do i need to add a special autorization in the manifest?

Comment: Are you sure you are deploying the last version to the Phone? Delete All bin/obj files, uninstall the app from your device and try again.

Comment: yes it does. I just switched the background color from green to white. Changing the text color to red only works in the emulator. Not the phone... to make sure i just tried to clean, rebuild, redeploy... the text color wont change, just the background color! very frustrating and time consuming for such a basic thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181625/discussion-between-martin-mightymart-lauzon-and-bruno-caceiro).

Comment: Seems like its an issue with Android 7.0 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17139

Comment: Seems like no a lot of people ARE INTERESTED and it was quite an issue. I have a workaround though. By reverting to the default font and contrast behavior of the phone it is now working as with the emulator. My behaviors work as well. Both changing the text color to red according to the context/logic.